# Set the maximum recursion depth while serializing a Django model with Foreign key to JSON

Tags: django, google-app-engine, json

I have a Django model created for Google's App Engine,

```
Model A():
  propA = ReferenceProperty(B)

Model B():
  propB = ReferenceProperty(C)

Model C():
  propC = ReferenceProperty(B)
```

I have written custom Django serializer which will fetch the data for the ReferenceProperty(s) and serialize that along the initial model.

The problem occurs when I try to serialize an instance of **Model A**. My custom serializer will try to get **propA**, which contains a reference to **Model C** so the serializer will fetch **Model C**, which contains a reference to **Model B** and the recursion goes on and on. Is there any way to stop the recursion after a depth of say 2??

My serializer is a customized version of [link text](http://code.google.com/p/dojango/source/browse/trunk/dojango/util/__init__.py#97)

**P.S:** I am willing to publish my code if that seems to needed. I have not currently attached the code since I am not at my development machine.

Thanks,
Arun Shanker Prasad.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your functions to take a 'depth' argument. Any time you follow a ReferenceProperty, call the function with depth one less than the depth that was passed in. If a function is called with depth==0, return None, or whatever other placeholder value is suitable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do recursion properly? Any recursive operation must have a [base case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_algorithms), otherwise it will continue forever, as your problem indicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find a serializer that works with Google App Engine and follows relationships.  Would it be possible for you to post the modified code you used to do this?